# Angular 2 beta: ngFor and expressions

Tags: angular, ngfor

I use the following code in a component and nothing renders though location is set with the right value:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="#dailyForecast of location.forecast.list">
    <h4>{{dailyForecast.dt * 1000 }} </h4>
</div>
```

I guess Angular 2 cannot deal with `location.forecast.list` though it's a valid array of objects in my TypeScript component class.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information.  This simple plunker works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/yiEOm59W3nfOjSi37iRU?p=preview

Comment: either provide some more code for better understanding or try to use elvis operator ( `?` ) like this in your code. `*ngFor="#dailyForecast of location.forecast?.list"`

Comment: I'll give a try to the Elvis operator. That may be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide more code.

You should to deal with 'location == null' and 'dailyForecast == null'

try those code:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="#dailyForecast of location?.forecast?.list">
    <h4>{{dailyForecast?.dt * 1000 }} </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. location is loaded through an AJAX request so that might be it. Not sure why they changed that, it was just great in Angular 1.